# System of differential equations (norm of the solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Given the following system:

$u_{1}'(t)+2u_{1}(t)-u_{2}(t)+(u_{1}(t))^3=0  \forall t>0$,

$u_{2}'(t)-u_{1}(t)+2u_{2}(t)+(u_{2}(t))^3=0  \forall t>0$,

$u_{1}(0)=1, u_{2}(0)=1$

I have trouble understanding why we have $||\vec{u}(t)||^2\leq2$.

I know that the $2$ is obviously linked to the initial condition, but I dont understand why the norm squared is bounded by it. I suppose that this might also have something to do with the associated matrix being definite positive. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if we rewrite this system in polar coordinates?

Comment: @MichaelLee I have no idea what this means in this context. Do you mean writing it in terms of vectors? I've done that already.

Comment: What I mean is that we can make the substitution $u_1(t) = r(t)\cos(\theta(t))$ and $u_2(t) = r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$ and thereby get an equivalent system of differential equations in $r$ and $\theta$. Consider that $r = \|u\|$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks, yes, this kind of works, but is there an approach using vectors?

Comment: Of course. Your objective is to show that the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ is what's called a "trapping region." To do this, you can show that the vector field points inward on the boundary of the trapping region (i.e. the vector field dotted with the inward-pointing normal is strictly positive everywhere on the boundary).

Comment: That is to say, the vector field $(u_1', u_2')$, in case that was unclear.